# How to serialize a class containing queues for XML?

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance, serialization, queue

I have a class called GamePrototype that I would like to serialize for XML use, containing the following members:

```
public class GamePrototype
{
    private string mPath;
    private bool[] isHumanPlayer;
    private Queue<CardPrototype> mKickStack;
    private Queue<CardPrototype> mMainDeck;
    private Queue<CardPrototype> mStarterDecks;
    private Queue<CardPrototype> mSuperVillianStack;
    private Queue<CardPrototype> mWeaknessStack;
    private Queue<PlayerHero> mPlayableHeroes;
    public Queue<CardPrototype>[] mStartingLocations;
}
```

I have been trying to serialize the class data with this method. "this" refers to an instance of the above-mentioned class:

```
public void XMLShelf(string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer boxPacker = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GamePrototype));
        StreamWriter boxPlacer = new StreamWriter(path);

        boxPacker.Serialize(boxPlacer, this);
        boxPlacer.Close();
    }
```

I have getters and setters for most if not all of them, but I'm getting two errors I don't know how to avoid:

```
Exception:Thrown: "You must implement a default accessor on 
System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[[Cards.GameBuilding.CardPrototype, Cards, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it inherits from 
ICollection."...
```

and

```
Exception:Thrown: "There was an error reflecting type 
'Cards.GameBuilding.GamePrototype'." (System.InvalidOperationException)
```

I've read in other posts that in the current situation, this class is not serializable because of the queues. That information might be outdated? I'm not sure, but my questions are:

Is there a way to easily transfer these queues into Lists just for serialization?
  Will I need to do this for all classes these members belong to as well? For example, Card prototype contains one queue and one stack.

Thank you very much for any help you might give me.

Comment: [Queue<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has Serializable attribute, so I don't think this is the reason you cant serialize. Please add code that you have(your wrote that you have properties for them, any attributes?), exception you getting, what kind of serializer you using and how you serializing.

Comment: Error please - exact, not "like".

Comment: I updated my post, and added a second exception I noticed during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what serialization you are using.
Using ISerializable it works just fine.

```
[Serializable]
class Program : ISerializable
{
    public Program() { }

    public Queue<int> Queue = new Queue<int>(); 

    private unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pr = new Program();
        pr.Queue.Enqueue(1034);

        using (var stream = File.Create("path.txt"))
        {
            var bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            bformatter.Serialize(stream, pr);
        }

        using (var stream = File.Open("path.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            pr = (Program)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("program " + pr.Queue.Peek()); //prints 1034
        Console.Read();
    }

    public Program(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        Queue = (Queue<int>)info.GetValue("queue", typeof(Queue<int>));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("queue", Queue);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement default accessor for the Queue because the XMLSerializer need it to enum the items, and also the Add method.

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableQueue : Queue<MyObject>
{
    public MyObject this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (MyObject o in this)
            {
                if (count == index)
                    return o;
                count++;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Add(MyObject r)
    {
        Enqueue(r);   
    }
}
```

This is a Queue that could be serialized to XML.